# Using spark in Databricks via a python script

Tags: pyspark, databricks, streamlit

I am trying to deploy a streamlit app on databricks.
To do so, I use the command: !streamlit run myApp.py

Everytime I try to do getOrCreate, I get an error from databricks stating I cannot create a new session and should use getOrCreate method of SparkContext and use the shared context, which inturn returns this same message again.

I would like to know if there is anyway I can pass my SparkSession from **notebook** to my streamlit **myApp.py file**, or create the session successfully.

My code closely resembles below code.

> myApp.py

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Initialize SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(master="local", appName="MyApp")

# Create SparkSession from SparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sc.getConf()).getOrCreate()
#Tried the below syntaxes as well
#Spark=SparkSession.getActiveSession() ## Returns null
#other ways to create spark session and spark context

# Stop the SparkContext when done to release resources
sc.stop()
```

Comment: Are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: why do you want to use python file when databricks giving notebook option

Comment: @s.polam, I am using a python file as I am trying to run a streamlit app which needs a python file.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula, I am using AWS databricks

Comment: SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() should work. If you want to pass your properties, you could do SparkSession.builder.config("appName", "myApp").getOrCreate()

Comment: @user2704177, it did not work in databricks, some people who posted on databricks community had the same issue, I was able to fix it by using the databricks-connect api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by utilizing the databricks-connect API.